# Spring & MongoCursor & Jackson JsonNode (Database conversion)

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, jackson

I have a problem parsing a String I got from MongoCursor to work with JsonNode. I'm trying to get the MongoCursor's returned Json to work with my Spring SQL POJO, so I can insert it to my SQL database. Basically this is a database conversion, and SQL end is just for history storage. I didn't use spring's mongo, because the fields are somewhat different than the POJO's.(MongoDB and SQL have slightly different schema)

Currently, it works by using pattern matcher/ string split and replace then HashMap them so I can get a key and value pair of each field and then insert that into my spring POJO. I know I can also use jackson's POJO to work, but was told to use jsonNode as a better solution. There must be something i'm missing.

In the Jackson docs, the format of a "json" string is:

> { \"color\" : \"Black\", \"type\" : \"BMW\" }

However, that is not going to be the case of what MongoCursor returns me with. With the cursor, I get something like:

> Document{{_id=G8HQW9123, User=test}}

which I used string pattern matcher and replaceAll to reduce to:

> {_id:G8G8HQW9123, User:test}

However, jackson's slashes and double quotes are throwing me off and unable to parse that. Am I missing something? or do I have to actually add in those slashes & quotes in my code to make things work? Currently getting parse error which requests double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing something here.

`MongoCursor` is returning you a `Document` Object, not a `String`.

Are you calling `Document.toString()` and working with the String result?

There should be no need for you to be doing any String parsing at all.  You should be able to just take the `Document` Object from Mongo and call the getter functions on it to get the fields out that you need, which will preserve their data types as well (strings, numbers, booleans and dates), for example check all the functions on the `BsonDocument` class Javadocs: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/org/bson/BsonDocument.html

Comment: Java IDE was telling me to use MongoCursor. Which doesn't have any getter functions, I had to use tostring to output anything. I'm gonna look at the Document object once I get to that computer on monday..

Thanks for the hint